# Why is Git Bash not able to display the prompts properly when running npm init gatsby?

Tags: node.js, gatsby, git-bash

[image: Everything seems to be updated, but the terminal window doesn't work in displaying the prompts.]

I am trying to follow the Quick Start guide for Gatsby. My terminal starts glitching out (see image) after running `npm init gatsby`.
I am on Windows.

I expect the prompt to be usable. I tried updating node as well as Git for Windows. Nothing changed when doing this.